# Are there any values for which the reverse triangle equality does not hold?

Tags: analysis

By the reverse triangle inequality, I mean
$\big||x|−|y|\big|\leq|x−y|$.

For this reverse triangle inequality, are there any values of $x$ and $y$ where the inequality does not hold? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

By the triangle inequality
$$|x|= |x-y+y|\le |x-y|+|y|$$

$$|y|= |y-x+x|\le |y-x|+|x|=|x-y|+|x|$$

We have proven that it holds for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, so there is no counterexample. It is a true statement.